# JQuery fade with loop and delay

Tags: jquery, loops, fade

I have 2 Divs stacked on top of each other.

I need a really simple function that will:

a) Wait for 3 seconds and then
b) FadeOut the top Div to reveal the second Div
c) Wait 3 seconds again and then
d) FadeIn the top Div again
e) Loop back again

Can anyone offer any advice?

Many thanks

Comment: The behavior is a bit unclear: for (b), do you want the top div to fade out and the second div to fade in? and (d) would the second div fade out again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an attempt.

```
function foo() {
    jQuery("#mydiv").animate({opacity: 1.0}, {duration: 3000})
        .animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 3000})
        .animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 3000})
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, {duration: 3000, complete: foo})
}
```

Note: To pause, just call animate over a property with the same target value as it is right now. The last animate calls the the same function as callback.

PS: Does it cause stack overflow over time?

Comment: Is there anyway to stop this loop once it has started? Like, on click stop loop forever?

Answer (score 2):

if the two divs have ids of "id1" and "id2", and id2 is the upper one then the code would be like:

```
function fadeIn() {
  $("id2").animate({opacity:0},500);
  setTimeout(fadeOut,3500);
}

function fadeOut() {
  $("id2").animate({opacity:1},500);
  setTimeout(fadeIn,3500);
}

function startAnim() {
  setTimeout(fadeIn,3000);
}
```

startAnim() starts the animation cycle , which you should call @ the start. Then fadeIn & Out keep animating id2 and setting timeouts for each other. The delay is 3500 , as you wanted 3 seconds of delay (ie. 3000ms) and 500 for the previous animation to complete. This could have been done using a callback on animate , but that's more messy.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you're looking for (I think). It uses an unordered-list, but you could switch it out for div's or just put your div's inside of the list items like I've done below.

Here's the jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var j = 0;
     var delay = 2000; //millisecond delay between cycles
     function cycleThru(){
             var jmax = $("ul#cyclelist li").length -1;
             $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")")
                     .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,400)
                     .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
                     .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 400, function(){
                             (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
                             cycleThru();
                     });
             };

     cycleThru();

});
```

...and some starting css...

```
ul#cyclelist {width:200px;border:solid;position:relative;overflow:hidden;height:200px}
ul#cyclelist li {font-size:1.4em;padding:20px;opacity:0;position:absolute}
```

You already have your HTML, but in case you need an example...

```
<ul id="cyclelist">
  <li><div>First Div</div></li>
  <li><div>Second Div</div></li>
  <li><div>Third Div</div></li>
</ul>
```

I'd love to take credit for this, but it's straight from CSS-Tricks http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/cycle-through-a-list/

Answer (score 1):

no one may ever see this, but just in case...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#picOne').fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
       $('#picTwo').delay(5000).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
});
</script>
```

this is without looping it though....

That would be

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function animate(){
        $('#picOne').fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
        $('#picTwo').delay(5000).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);    
    }
    animate();  
    setInterval(animate, 10000);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: So nice and simple, one line per item that needs to be fade-looped. I could hand this over to the designer and explained to change numbers to vary fading, nice.

Answer (score 0):

This attempt uses a small cookbook function wait from jquery.com.

The function doFading assumes the id of the top div to be "a4".

```
function doFading() {
      $("#a4").wait(3000)
      .fadeOut("slow")
      .wait(3000)
      .fadeIn("slow",doFading);
    }

$.fn.wait = function(time, type) {
        time = time || 1000;
        type = type || "fx";
        return this.queue(type, function() {
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(self).dequeue();
            }, time);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you also want to have it xfade. Use floyed's script but make the changes that I have used. Only problem is your first image you want shown should be the second one in the li elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {

         var j = 0;
         var delay = 5000; //millisecond delay between cycles
         function cycleThru(){
                 var jmax = $("ul#cyclelist li").length -1;
                 $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")")
                         .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,1000)
                         .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay);
             $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")").next().animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,1000);    
             $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")")
                         .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 1000, function(){
                                 (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j--;
                                 cycleThru();
                         });
                 };

         cycleThru();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I thought I would share what I did to accomplish this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 500;
    $("#mydiv").bind('fadein', function()
    {
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function()
        {
            $(this).delay(delay).trigger('fadeout');
        });
    });

    $("#mydiv").bind('fadeout', function()
    {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000, function()
        {
            $(this).delay(delay).trigger('fadein');
        });
    });

    $("#mydiv").fadeIn(1000, function()
    {
        $(this).trigger("fadein");
    });
});
```

then call this when you want it to stop

```
$("#mydiv").stop().hide();
```