# Fade two stacked texts with jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, fade, stacked

Based on 
[JQuery fade with loop and delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301529/jquery-fade-with-loop-and-delay)
How can I fade in out two text lines and not overlapping both?

My HTML:

```
<div id="div_1" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;"> aaa bbb ccc ddd eee </div>

<div id="div_2" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;"> 111 222 333 444 555 </div>
```

div_1 is first displayed and faded out, then div_2 fade in, then fade out, then div_1 fade in, and so on

Comment: Can you provide the HTML you are working with?

Comment: Put this as an edit to your original question and format it as code to make sure it display's correctly.

Comment: It is something like
`<div id="div_1" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;">
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
</div>


<div id="div_2" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;">
111 222 333 444 555` div_1 is first displayed and faded out, then div_2 fade in, then fade out, then div_1 fade in, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join two objects to be animated together using the `.add()` function:

```
$('#div1').add($('#div2')).fadeToggle();
```

http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: div_1 is first displayed and faded out while div_2 is hidden, then div_2 fade in, then fade out, then div_1 fade in, and so on

Comment: Here's my sample http://jsfiddle.net/ATBDt/2/ I see it good in Chrome Mac. Alternating fading text is displayed without fade overlapping. But... I added a comment in the 2nd. answer up.

Comment: Yes. But boths text overlaying, not in different line. http://jsfiddle.net/ATBDt/6/ The problem here is that I want div1 fade out to white and then, immediately, div2 fade in (not mixed display)

Comment: Great!  I reduced time to half to get it similar to  ATBDt/2/. I've tested in some OS/browsers and did not find problems. Thanks!

Comment: I had edited the answer and put your /13 code but I still see the old one. Checkmark is already green.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not elegant, but effective.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function fade1() {
    $('#div1').delay(2000).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000).delay(2000);
}
function fade2() {
    $('#div2').delay(2000).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000).delay(2000);
}
function fade0() {
    $('#div2').fadeOut(0);
    $('#div2').delay(2000);
}
setInterval('fade1()', 1);
setInterval('fade2()', 1);
</script>

<body onload="fade0(); fade1(); fade2();">
```

Comment: It is working fine in Chrome-Mac and safari. In FF7-Linux and Mac behavior is different, not de desired.
Also found that after a while, working on other Chorme tabs and returning to my test tab, behavior has changed: both divs are fadeIn and Out at the same time, delay between both is lost.