# jQuery fading glow special text effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, css-transitions

I'd like to make black error message text "glow" with a red outline that fades away after a second, but, if updated, return to "full glow" and start fading away again, even if it hadn't faded away completely in the first place.  Is there a fairly easy jQuery/ CSS way to do this?  I think two simultaneous fading techniques would compete with each other, being asynchronous and all, and I don't quite know how to generate the glowing effect, or if it's even possible using standard styling.

Comment: Googling for "css animated glow" brought me [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-glowing-link-effect/#fbid=bsgdXahsa5j).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use any external plugins, you can do this with just **jQuery 1.8** and **css3** but it isn't easy. You need to combine css3 `text-shadow` property with `animate()`

**UPDATE:** Bugs fixed.

[**Here is working jsFiddle text glow effect.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jf4vB/32/)

**jQuery:**

```
var red = $(".red");
red.click(function() {
   if ( !$(this).is(':animated') )

    //you just adjust here
    red.glowEffect(0,40,500);
    //which is:
    //red.glowEffect( start value , destination value , duration );
});

$.fn.glowEffect = function(start, end, duration) {
    var $this = this;
    return this.css("a", start).animate({
        a: end
    }, {
        duration: duration,
        step: function(now) {
            $this.css("text-shadow","0px 0px "+now+"px #c61a1a");
        }
    });
};​
```

**css:**

```
.red { text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #c61a1a; }
```

**Note:** No need to define vendor prefixes like `-webkit- -ms- -moz- -o-` jQuery 1.8 fixes that automaticly.

**Source:** I've asked alike question last week, and great answers came:

[How to combine jQuery animate with css3 properties without using css transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062818/how-to-combine-jquery-animate-with-css3-properties-without-using-css-transitions)

Comment: Can this be interrupted and reset by itself?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Yes. You can do whatever animation you need mate, just adjust `red.glowEffect` function inside click. I explained and pointed that out in my update.

Comment: Hmm... that's not really what I was looking for.  It looks like this will ignore a subsequent animation if it is fading... I want it to reset to its "fresh, brightly glowing" state if the event occurs before the last animation finishes.

Comment: there is no example on your question so i did it this way, if you really understand this way, you realise that you can do anything with this

Comment: I've noticed this function does not work with a negative animation, f.e red.glowEffect(100,0,500); Which is part of what the op wants.

Comment: @Jan yes, which i try to underline it on my update. I will update my answer again.

Comment: Did some testing and it's because the css property "a" doesn't exist, so it always starts from 0.

Comment: @Jan Thank you very much, you discovered a bug (: i'll work on it. But there will be no problem if animation starts from `0` value.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs i've updated my answer and cleared bugs, i hope it would help.

Comment: Just to be clear, this solution always starts the animation from 0 so it won't be possible to make a fade-out effect with it, only fade-in. If that's OK with the op then fire away! :)

Comment: @Jan We fixed that problem mate: http://jsfiddle.net/qZRdZ/112/ and here is the question: [How to combine jQuery animate with css3 properties without using css transitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062818/how-to-combine-jquery-animate-with-css3-properties-without-using-css-transitions) **If you have better solution, post here.**

Answer (score 2):

A pure CSS3 solution stolen shamelessly from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-glowing-link-effect/#fbid=bsgdXahsa5j):

```
a.glow, a.glow:hover, a.glow:focus {  
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: #aaf;  
    text-shadow: none;  
    -webkit-transition: 500ms linear 0s;  
    -moz-transition: 500ms linear 0s;  
    -o-transition: 500ms linear 0s;  
    transition: 500ms linear 0s;  
    outline: 0 none;  
} 
a.glow:hover, a.glow:focus  {  
    color: #fff;  
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ffc, 1px -1px 8px #fff;  
}
```

Comment: interesting... I will try this out.

Comment: This has a very nice effect, but only answers the first part of the question; how would I implement this glow and have it slowly fade away, unless the event that made it glow and started it fading was fired again, at which point it would "reset" to full "glow-on"?

Comment: Have you tried tinkering with it? If you separate the styles for `a.glow` and `a.glow:hover, a.glow:focus`, then you can adjust the timing for the on and off transitions separately. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GzTC7/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of barlasapaydin's answer that works with negative animations:

```
$.fn.glowEffect = function(start, end, duration, callback) {
    // Fetch last animation position
    if (this.data("last-glow")) 
        start = this.data("last-glow");

    return this.animate({
        'placeholder': end // This can be anything, it's just a placeholder to allow the animation to run
    }, {
        duration:duration,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            // Calculate current position
            now = parseInt(start + (end - start)*(fx.pos));
            // Set current animation position
            $(fx.elem).css("text-shadow","0px 0px "+now+"px #c61a1a")
                // Save position (if animation is interrupted)
                .data("last-glow", now);
        },
        complete:callback
    });
};

$(".red").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .stop()
        .glowEffect(0,50,1000, // Fade in
                    function() 
                    { 
                        $(this).glowEffect(50,0,1000);  // Fade out
                    });
});
```

The code's a bit convoluted but it works perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jf4vB/38/

Some helpful third-party documentation on the "step" object:

http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/

Comment: lol, nice try mate, we solve the problem on my answer which you find (: this works perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/qZRdZ/112/

Comment: you can inspect the steps of this plugin from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062818/how-to-combine-jquery-animate-with-css3-properties-without-using-css-transitions

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery UI's animation plugin you can create a fuzzy red shadow behind your text (using CSS3 properties) and then animate its opacity, size, etc.

Comment: To be sure, if you're going to use CSS3 properties, you may as well go all the way and animate it with CSS transitions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the CSS3 "text-shadow" property for the glowing effect, and $(".textid").stop().addClass("glow", 1000); for the animation.

EDIT: Okay, that did not work: http://jsfiddle.net/2pBxP/ :)

Answer (score 0):

To make a looping animation in JQuery you can do something like this:

[JQuery fade with loop and delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301529/jquery-fade-with-loop-and-delay)

You can then use CSS3 to add a text glow (or shadow), but note that this is not supported in some browsers.