# How to animate text with css font-weight property in jQuery ? normal to bold

Tags: jquery, css, animation, fonts, jquery-animate

I am trying to animation like opacity effect, which turns text bolder slowly. Tried usual `animate()` method but didn't work. Searched for it but coundn't find any example. **Is it possible to do this?**

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2EECN/28/)

**jQuery:**

```
var Text = $('h1');
Text.click(function() {
    Text.animate({'font-weight':'bold'},600)
        .delay(200).animate({'font-weight':'normal'},600);
});
```

Comment: tried to explore CSS3 transitions ?

Comment: @Roko nope `/:` [**i've manage to do with text-shadow**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186768/jquery-fading-glow-special-text-effect/12186830#12186830), but i bealive this way will be better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **EDIT, April 2021:** This is now possible to achieve either with `transition: font-weight` or more seamlessly with [variable fonts](https://v-fonts.com/).

## Sadly I think this is **impossible.**

Each character in a font has a specific shape. In addition, similar characters in different weights weights are also distinct—a bold character does not simply have a mathematically-defined offset from its regular counterpart.

It would be very easy to jump from regular to **bold** or *italic* with jQuery.css(), but there it is currently impossible to jQuery.animate() the transition of font-weight in the browser. It is hard to do in animation as well because there are no “frames” between the different weights, as they are all drawn separately.

## However,

If you choose a font that has a consistant spacing of letters for the different weights—such as [Exo](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Exo)—and do a stepped animation from thin to black you might come close to the desired result.

Starting from your jsFiddle that is what I could come up with:

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2EECN/133/)

And the rather dumb Javascript behind it:

```
Text.click(function() {
            
  Text.css({'font-weight':200});
  setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':300})}, 30)
  setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':400})}, 60)
  setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':500})}, 90)
  setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':600})},120)
  setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':700})},150)
  setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':800})},180)
  setTimeout(function(){ Text.css({'font-weight':900})},210)

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ve been looking at answers on SO for a long time, thought it was about time I tried helping people out with the few things I know.

As for my response, the major drawback is that you need a font with many weights, which is hard to find in free fonts. Also I was very limited in the number of links I could post because of my reputation of 1 :)

Comment: I think it's possible now.. with  `transition: font-weight`

https://codepen.io/madshensel/pen/ZOYwpy

Answer (score 4):

You could use pure CSS, using `text-shadow` and the pseudo class `:hover`, with a `transition` to animate it

```css
.animate {
  font-size: 35px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.animate:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate">StackOverflow</div>
```

---

Also you could use jQuery, by using `addClass()`:

```js
$("#animateBold").click(function() {
  $(".animate").addClass("bold");
});
```

```css
.animate {
  font-size: 30px;
}
/* Then .bold CSS class */
.bold {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animate">StackOverflow<div>
<button id="animateBold">Animate!</button>
```

---

Or, if you wanted a toggle effect, using a [`ternary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator:

```
($(".animate").hasClass("bold")) ? $(".animate").removeClass("bold") : $(".animate").addClass("bold");
```

```js
$("#toggleBold").click(function() {
  ($(".animate").hasClass("bold")) ? $(".animate").removeClass("bold") : $(".animate").addClass("bold");
});
```

```css
.animate {
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.bold {
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px black, 0 0 2px black;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animate">StackOverflow<div>
<button id="toggleBold">Animate!</button>
```

Comment: I thought this was a cool effect to use after an action was performed, I added a 2nd class to fade out the effect.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with font-variation-settings (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variation-settings)

You can check it in action on this website when hovering over brand names - https://www.ahundredmonkeys.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31568008)

Answer (score -3):

Technically font-weight can be a number, like 100 or 800, but
practically speaking browsers only implement either normal or bold.
Animate takes either a number or one of "hide", "show", or "toggle".
So your "bold" won't work.
In theory you could set the font-weight to a number then pass in a
number to animate. (400 is "normal" weight, 700 is bold [1])
Alas this doesn't seem to work in jQuery.

BUT! You CAN do this with CSS3, although it wont work on Internet explorer, your desired effect will reach more than 50% of the population. See this for an example.

http://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_transition-property.cfm

Comment: That does not work, if you change your hover properties to just `.resize:hover { font-weight:bold; }` you will see it is not animated, it just switches between bold and normal.

Comment: Odd that it looks as if it's animated to bold, I didn't test it I left the testing to you, sorry that this option doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks, although it was pointed out that this was not animated, it has worked for the purpose I needed it for, so thanks @Shannon.