# In JQuery using animate function how do I make text bold, change its colour and make it larger?

Tags: jquery

In this piece of code I have managed to get the text to move 250px to the left, however I do not know how to make the text bold, larger or change it's colour, do I need a special plugin for colour changing also?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#animate").click(function(){
        $("#green_box").animate({
          left: '250px',
       });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Please see: https://api.jquery.com/animate/ *The `.animate()` method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property. The only required parameter is a plain object of CSS properties. This object is similar to the one that can be sent to the .css() method, except that the range of properties is more restrictive.* This will not be the best method to make the changes. I would consider a CSS Animation.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433645/how-to-animate-text-with-css-font-weight-property-in-jquery-normal-to-bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the alternative:

```
$(function(){
  $("#animate").click(function(){
    $("#green_box").animate({
      left: '250px',
      fontSize: '16px'
     }, 2000, function(){
       $(this).css({
         "font-weight": "bold",
         color: "green"
       });
     });
   });
});
```

This will animate the movement and once complete (in 2 seconds), the text will be changed. Personally, I would simply change or add a Class to the element. This way you can assign the CSS with a Class name.

If you want to use Jquery UI, then you can animate more elements. See more: https://jqueryui.com/animate/

```
$(function(){
  $("#animate").click(function(){
    $("#green_box").animate({
      left: '250px',
      fontSize: '16px',
      color: 'green'
     }, 2000);
   });
});
```