# Jquery fade in element with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery of images that needs to be fadded in, one by one. That means, after the first faddes in, the second one fades in, then the third, fourth and so on...

I've tried that with...

```
var object = $('#gallery-id img');
    for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        var timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(object[i]).fadeIn(300);
        },500);
    }
```

but it doesn't work. Images are not even shown, let alone fadded. What am i doing wrong?

I've also found a [stacks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301529/jquery-fade-with-loop-and-delay) and tried this...

```
    var object = $('#lightbox-galerija-id img');
    for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        $(object[i]).delay(1000).fadeIn(300);
    }
```

but that only delays for a second, and displays all of the images at once.

Comment: Try with `(i+1) * 1000` like `$(object[i]).delay((i+1) * 1000).fadeIn(300);`

Comment: it works. thank you very much. Could you tell me why did it work? I'm guessing that delay's are stacked and if they are all the same, then that delay is executed.

Comment: Thanks again. You saved me alot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var object = $('#gallery-id img');
    for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        var timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            object.eq(i).delay(i*500).fadeIn(300);
        },500);
    }
```